# Resizing Amazon RDS instances and data loss

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've just upgraded a small Postgres RDS instance from 5Gb to 10Gb and moved from Magnetic to SSD.

Logging in, where previously I had a whole database ('named_db'), this has now disappeared.

I've got 7 day snapshots, but even restoring the oldest of these does not have the database. I was logged in and accessing fresh data on this DB as recently as 3 days ago.

Is it possible that the snapshots have not backed up this database at all?

Comment: You should write to the AWS support team. The snapshots from 3 days should have the DB, unless someone else with access to the servers deleted those!